# Cleaning an array doesn't update my ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have very strange behavior, it is simple I have a list and this is the HTML

```
 <div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--bordered kt-portlet--head--noborder">
      <div class="kt-portlet__head">
        <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
          <h3 (click)="teste()" class="kt-portlet__head-title">
            Lista de imagens / ordem
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="kt-portlet__body">

        <div class="grid">
          <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of imageList; let i=index">
            <div class="item-content">
              <span (click)="teste()" class="close pointer">&times;</span>
              <img [src]="image.thumb" (click)="open(i)" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

I make a test function for this I put a function here

```
 <h3 (click)="teste()" class="kt-portlet__head-title">
                Lista de imagens / ordem
              </h3>
```

and here

```
<span (click)="teste()" class="close pointer">&times;</span>
```

The same function that executes here in my component.ts file

```
public teste() {
    this.imageList = [];
  }
```

Why on earth this works if I press from **H3 and not from the SPAN?**, I tried to change for a button, tried detector changes and nothing seems to work.

one observation I using the Muuri library in this grid and when I open this component he is executing this

```
  setTimeout(() => {
            const grid = new Muuri.default('.grid', {
              items: '.item',
              dragEnabled: true,
              dragSortPredicate: {
              threshold: 20,
              action: 'move',
              layout: {
                fillGaps: true,
              },
            }}).on('dragMove', (item, event) => {
              this.isDragging = true;
            }).on('dragReleaseEnd', (item, event) => {
              this.isDragging = false;
            });
          });
```

I don't know if this is the problem, but when I press on H3 still works but not inside the ngFor.

Comment: Could you add the css for these two classes in your question `class="close pointer"`

Comment: here .close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    opacity: .5;
}
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: Are you sure that `teste` is executed? You can check with `console.log("teste")`.

Comment: You can add `markForCheck` and `detectChanges` to make sure angular will update

Comment: can you provide stackblitz with minimum reproduction ?

Comment: yes i will make a stackblitz